# Immutable state not refreshing

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am making a react app, I have a "categories" collection and a presentation layer with a button to remove a category. My redux state refresh if I reload the page otherwise is persistent. I don't understand why it is not working since seems immutable to me, plus I am using the same pattern in another component and works fine. What am I missing ?

Here the reducer:

```
import {DELETE_CATEGORY} from './../../actionType';
const initialState = {
  singleCategory: {},
  categories: []
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case DELETE_CATEGORY:
    return {
      ...state,
      categories: state.categories.filter (category=>category._id !== category.payload)
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

By the way if I refresh the page the store is filtered correctly.
Here is my action:

```
// Delete Category by id
export const deleteCategory = (categoryId) => dispatch => {
  console.log('disp');
  axios
    .delete(`/api/categories/${categoryId}`)
    .then( success => {
      dispatch(successMessage);
      return dispatch({
        type: DELETE_CATEGORY,
        payload: categoryId
      })
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data
      }),
    );
};
```

Here is my component:

```
class ShowCategoriesPage extends Component {

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.getCategories()
  }
  handleDeleteCategory = (categoryId) => {
    this.props.deleteCategory(categoryId);
  }
  render() {
    const { categories } = this.props.categories;
    return (
      <SidebarLayout>
        {categories.map(category => (
          <CategoryCard
            name={category.name}
            type={category.type}
            id={category._id}
            handleDeleteCategory={this.handleDeleteCategory}
          />
        ))}
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{marginTop: '36px'}} >
        ADD NEW CATEGORY
      </Button>
      </SidebarLayout>
    )
  }
}
```

and this is the  component:

```
const SimpleCard = ({ classes, name, type, id, deleteCategory })=>{

  const onDeleteCategory = (categoryId) => {
    deleteCategory(categoryId);
  }

  return (
    <Card className={classes.card}>
      <CardContent>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h2">
          {name}
        </Typography>
        <Typography className={classes.pos} color="textSecondary">
          {type}
        </Typography>
        <Button variant="small" color="primary" style={{marginTop: '36px'}} onClick={()=>onDeleteCategory(id)}>
        REMOVE
      </Button>
        <Button variant="small" color="primary" style={{marginTop: '36px'}} >
        EDIT
      </Button>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

I read the official redux documentation and it advise to use splice or filter like I did, can you understand why redux state is not refreshing clicking on delete button?

I want to avoid to force refresh the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure this line is correct

```
      categories: state.categories.filter (category=>category._id !== category.payload)
```

and not

```
      categories: state.categories.filter (category=>category._id !== action.payload)
```